# Destroy chart.js bar graph to redraw other graph

Tags: javascript, html, charts, chart.js

I am using the Chart.js library to draw a bar graph, but I want to destroy the bar graph and make a new graph in the same canvas. I have tried this way to clear the canvas:

```
var chart = new Chart( ctx, {
                                            type : "bar",
                                            data : data1,
                                            options : options
                                            });
                                                                                                                                                                                                      
                                            $("#btn1").on("click", function() { 
                                                if (chart) chart.destroy();
                                                var chart = new Chart( ctx, {
                                            type : "bar",
                                            data : data1,
                                            options : options
                                            });
                                            });
```

Am I calling it right? On ButtonClick I call this function which uses the same canvas.

```
<canvas id="graph" width="700px" height="300px"></canvas>

var ctx = $("#graph");
```

EDIT:

I change the code but only work for the first time I click in the button, when I change for the second time, it won't work again.

The trickiest is that to work I need to change the name of the 2 graph

```
var ctx = document.getElementById('graph');
                                            var myChart = new Chart( ctx, {
                                            type : "bar",
                                            data : data1,
                                            options : options
                                            });
                                                                                                                                                                                                      
                                            
                                            $("#btn2").on("click", function() {
                                            if (myChart) myChart.destroy();   
                                            var ctx = document.getElementById('graph');
                                            var chart = new Chart( ctx, {
                                            type : "bar",
                                            data : data2,
                                            options : options
                                            });
                                            });
```

Comment: You're using jQuery but chartjs expects the canvas element itself. You probably need to replace `var ctx = $("#graph");` with `var ctx = document.getElementById("graph");`

Comment: I tried to change but the problem persists

Comment: What exactly is the problem though? Did you check the console for error messages? When I try this, it works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/ewL2agqm/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove old chart and append new chart to div using chartjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71093596/how-to-remove-old-chart-and-append-new-chart-to-div-using-chartjs)

Comment: the problem is that the graph still shows the previous one, I changed to the code you put but the problem isn't fixed

Comment: I change the code but sometimes when I change the buttons stop working, I think that the problem can be the local of the braces, because the code is right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to all for the help but I already got it, and for future doubts, I will put my solution here to the people who need

```
    var ctx = document.getElementById('graph').getContext('2d');
                                var myBarChart = new Chart( ctx, {
                                type : "bar",
                                data : data1,
                                options : options
                                });
                                                                                                                                                                                          
                                $("#btn1").on("click", function() { 
                                    var context1 = document.getElementById('graph').getContext('2d');
                                    if (myBarChart) myBarChart.destroy();
                                    myBarChart = new Chart( context1, {
                                type : "bar",
                                data : data1,
                                options : options
                                });
                                });

                                $("#btn2").on("click", function() {
 var context2 = document.getElementById('graph').getContext('2d');
              if (myBarChart) myBarChart.destroy();
              myBarChart = new Chart( context2, {
              type : "bar",
              data : data2,
              options : options
              });
              });
```