# Update Chart JS with Ajax

Tags: php, ajax, symfony, chart.js, twig

So i try to update my Chart (ChartJS) in my Twig Template with Ajax.
I have a table which is filled with different categories. If the user click on one tr, the Chart in the twig-template should update and show the data.

So the Ajax-Response work, i get the full data which i need for my form.

```
$.ajax({
     url:  "{{ (path('categorie.loadchart')) }}",
     type: 'POST',
     data: { 'id': id, },
     success: function (response) {
   
    
  $('#chart').replaceWith(
   
  $(response.responseText).find('#chart'));
 

     },
     error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){}
 });
```

Here is an example of the data i get: `string(3) "413" array(12) { [1]=> float(73) [2]=> float(184) [3]=> float(449) [4]=> float(372) [5]=> float(604) [6]=> float(426) [7]=> float(159) [8]=> float(215) [9]=> float(321) [10]=> float(301) [11]=> float(100) [12]=> float(846) }` But the chart dont update..

My understanding problem is : I dont know how to update the chart.
I thought i just call the path of my function loadchart, create a new chart
 `$chart = $chartBuilder->createChart(Chart::TYPE_BAR);`… then after i set the data in the controller i render it. Like :

```
return $this->render('category/chart.html.twig', array(
    'chart' => $chart,
    
));
```

the category/chart.html.twig ist included in my main.twig:

```
   <div id="chart" class="border-left-primary">
 {% include 'categorie/chart.html.twig' %}

</div>
```

But this not works. Through my research i think i should just change the data of the chart and update it. Like "chart.update()", but i really dont know where/how i can update the chart. Normally in the controller, but with what command?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: So when you get your Ajax data, can you not just run an update function for ChartJS? (I've not used ChartJS), maybe [this](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/updates.html)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Destroy chart.js bar graph to redraw other graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71109485/destroy-chart-js-bar-graph-to-redraw-other-graph)

Comment: Thank you for your fast respond. I already saw the 2 posts. There they update the chart via javascript, but i create/render my chart in my Controller and pass it via return to the twig, so i dont really know how to use the update() funciton in my controller..

Comment: You're question states you use ajax, thus you'll need to use javascript

Comment: I use js, but just to get the id of the category which is clicked and pass that in formation to my function in my controller. I cant just do sth like that: So i dont know how to adress the chart in javascript. I tried : var chart = document.getElementById("chart");
chart.update();
. I updated my question with more information

Comment: What have you tried to resolve your problem? Where are you stuck? `<div id"chart"` looks broken to me

Comment: But you aren't returning HTML in your response, only data

Comment: To be honest i thought i returning HTML through my function categoriy.loadchart, because there i return the html.twig. But maybe this was wrong.